# Connect to MongoDB Database using Python

Tags: python, pymongo

I am new in using python and I want to try first connecting to mongodb database using python

This is my code but is has error

```
import pymongo

DATABASE_NAME = "testdb"
DATABASE_HOST = "mongodb://10.10.100.100:22222"

DATABASE_USERNAME = "testuserid"
DATABASE_PASSWORD = "testpass"

try:
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient(DATABASE_HOST)
    myclient.test.authenticate( DATABASE_USERNAME , DATABASE_PASSWORD )
    mydb = myclient[DATABASE_NAME]
    print("[+] Database connected!")
except Exception as e:
    print("[+] Database connection error!")
    raise e
```

10.10.100.100 is just my sample address and also 22222 is sample port

Comment: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/authentication.html

Answer (score 0):

```
DATABASE_URI = f"mongodb://{DATABASE_USERNAME}:{DATABASE_PASSWORD}@{DATABASE_HOST}"
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient(DATABASE_URI)
```